# Time for processing a batch of images at once is almost equal to processing them sequentially in order

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

#### System information

```
- What is the top-level directory of the model you are using: object_detection
- Have I written custom code (as opposed to using a stock example script provided in TensorFlow): No, just a small tweak for inference
- OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04):Ubuntu 16.04
- TensorFlow installed from (source or binary): conda
- TensorFlow version (use command below): 1.4.0
- GPU model and memory: Nvidia GTX 1060 6GB
```

#### Problem:

Theoretically, running inference on a batch of n images (n is the maximum number of images the GPU can accommodate) and 1 image should take almost the same time. I am trying to do batch inference using the `faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco's frozen_inference_graph`. Visualizing the frozen inference graph shows that the input is of shape (None,None,None,3), thus I can safely process a batch of images simultaneously. 
[image: screenshot 15]. But when I tried processing a batch of 1 image vs a batch of 10 images, I didn't get the same inference time

The last block in the object detection tutorial Ipython Notebook is modified as follows and the graph used is `faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco`.

```
import cv2
itr_num = 10
batch_size = 1
inference_times = []
with detection_graph.as_default():
    with tf.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
        # Definite input and output Tensors for detection_graph
        image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
        # Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was detected.
        detection_boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
        # Each score represent how level of confidence for each of the objects.
        # Score is shown on the result image, together with the class label.
        detection_scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
        detection_classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
        num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')
        for im_num in range(itr_num):
            images = [cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(TEST_IMAGE_PATHS[1]),cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) for _ in range(batch_size)]
            images = np.array(images)
            print(images.shape)
            assert len(images) == batch_size, "lists are not equal {}, {}".format(len(images),batch_size)
            start_time = time.time()
            (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
              [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
              feed_dict={image_tensor: images})
            print("The time taken for image set{} is {} secs".format(im_num+1,time.time()-start_time))
            inference_times.append(time.time()-start_time)
            # Visualization of the results of a detection.
#             vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
#               image_np,
#               np.squeeze(boxes),
#               np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
#               np.squeeze(scores),
#               category_index,
#               use_normalized_coordinates=True,
#               line_thickness=8)

inference_times = np.array(inference_times[1:])
print("average time for {} (images excluding the first image) is {}".format(itr_num-1,inference_times.mean()))
```

#### Output for batch_size=1

```
(1, 900, 1352, 3)
The time taken for image set1 is 2.029768228530884 secs
(1, 900, 1352, 3)
The time taken for image set2 is 0.12289047241210938 secs
(1, 900, 1352, 3)
The time taken for image set3 is 0.11852574348449707 secs
(1, 900, 1352, 3)
The time taken for image set4 is 0.12165331840515137 secs
(1, 900, 1352, 3)
The time taken for image set5 is 0.11874818801879883 secs
(1, 900, 1352, 3)
The time taken for image set6 is 0.11887550354003906 secs
(1, 900, 1352, 3)
The time taken for image set7 is 0.122528076171875 secs
(1, 900, 1352, 3)
The time taken for image set8 is 0.12240052223205566 secs
(1, 900, 1352, 3)
The time taken for image set9 is 0.1199343204498291 secs
(1, 900, 1352, 3)
The time taken for image set10 is 0.12351012229919434 secs
average time for 9 (images excluding the first image) is 0.12106058332655165
```

#### Output for batch_size = 10:

```
(10, 900, 1352, 3)
The time taken for image set1 is 2.459228992462158 secs
(10, 900, 1352, 3)
The time taken for image set2 is 0.9496431350708008 secs
(10, 900, 1352, 3)
The time taken for image set3 is 0.9487781524658203 secs
(10, 900, 1352, 3)
The time taken for image set4 is 0.9454429149627686 secs
(10, 900, 1352, 3)
The time taken for image set5 is 0.9377844333648682 secs
(10, 900, 1352, 3)
The time taken for image set6 is 0.9478261470794678 secs
(10, 900, 1352, 3)
The time taken for image set7 is 0.9489026069641113 secs
(10, 900, 1352, 3)
The time taken for image set8 is 0.9412193298339844 secs
(10, 900, 1352, 3)
The time taken for image set9 is 1.0171809196472168 secs
(10, 900, 1352, 3)
The time taken for image set10 is 0.938474178314209 secs
average time for 9 (images excluding the first image) is 0.9528606202867296
```

The time taken for a batch of 10 images processed together ~ 10 times the time taken to process a single image, Which shouldn't be the case. What am I missing here? Thanks.

> My question is: Why Tensorflow is taking 0.95 sec which is
>   approximately equal to 10*0.1(time for processing a single image) secs while doing batch processing?
>   shouldn't a batch of 10 images also take 0.1 secs? (due to
>   parallel processing?)

#### PS:

The time taken for inferring 1 image is almost twice as given in the model zoo bench mark (0.058).

Comment: So, what is the actual question? Are you asking for debugging help?

Comment: That is considered as _"please help me debug my code"_

Comment: I have noticed the same on my models. I guess there is no way to take benefits of having a batch in the gpu computation if all the cores are already busy treating one image and batch images are processed sequentially under the hood ? (this is a guess, I would appreciate your thoughts about it)

Comment: Have you tried serving batching? https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/batching/README.md and also this post seems suggest batching does help for per sample cost https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52765373/why-is-the-per-sample-prediction-time-on-tensorflow-and-keras-lower-when-predi